# Database msdb stuck in recovery

Tags: sql-server, recovery, msdb

I encountered a problem while testing recovering backups (Veritas BackUp Exec 2015, just for you to know).

Main Problem is: I couldnt restore the databases - looking on the target Server where I want to restore the DBs, SSMS tells me, 'msdb' database is being recovered.

I've already tried:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MSDB WITH NORECOVERY | ...WITH RECOVERY
```

The command was executed (no Errors), but nothing happened (even after restarting SQL Services & a Server restart).

I tried to set it offline, but running

```
ALTER DATABASE MSDB SET OFFLINE
```

tells me, that the msdb-Database can't be set as offline.

I need a way to get the msdb database out of recovery. Unless it will be recovered anyway, the current data is useless for me. Is there a way to just force it out of recovery (even if its damaged after executing the command)?

```
SELECT [state_desc] FROM [sys].[databases] WHERE [name] = N'msdb';
```

returns "RESTORING".

Comment: @Kin: thanks, that did the trick! Database was in a normal state, making it possible for BEX to recover the whole database - everything worked fine, thx! -> if you want to, write an answer below here and ill mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer :

```
restore database msdb with replace, recovery
```

**Note :** if the file location is same, then you dont need to use `with move` in the `restore` clause.